# 3 dependency drop down using struts and hibernate(country,state,city)

Tags: ajax, hibernate, combobox, struts2, drop-down-menu

I have there combo list. Country, state and city. I need to change the list according to the previous combolist like if I change the country I need get the corresponding statelist of that country and also if i select state then corresponding cities of that state. Can anyone please help me out to find an answer for this. Thanks

```
public String getStateNCityList() {
    logger.info("Enter getStateNCityList");
    try {
        AddressUtils addrUtil = new AddressUtils();
        this.stateList = addrUtil.getStateList(this.getCountryId());
        this.cityList = addrUtil.getCityList(this.getStateList().get(0).getAddressComboId());
        this.session.put("stateList", this.stateList);
        this.session.put("cityList", this.cityList);
        System.out.println("state list size "+this.stateList.size());
        System.out.println("city list size "+this.cityList.size());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e,e);
        return ERROR;
    }
    logger.info("Exit getStateNCityList");
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

//addressUtils.java

```
public List<AddressComboDetails> getCountryList(){
    List<AddressComboDetails> countryList = new ArrayList<AddressComboDetails>();
    try{
    String query=" addressComboTypeId="+ApplicationConstants.COMBO_COUNTRY;
    countryList=addressDao.getAddressComboDetailsByWhereClause(query);
    System.out.println("countryList size" +countryList.size());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in getCountryList" );
        logger.error(e,e);
    }
    return countryList;
}
```

//hibernate java class

```
public List<AddressComboDetails> getAddressComboDetailsByWhereClause(
        String whereClause) {
    logger.info("entered getAddresscomboDetailsByWhereClause ");
    List<AddressComboDetails> addressComboList = new ArrayList<AddressComboDetails>();
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String query = " from AddressComboDetails  where " + whereClause;
        System.out.println("Query is "+query);
        addressComboList = (List<AddressComboDetails>) session.createQuery(query).list();
        tx.commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.error("error in getAddresscomboDetailsByWhereClause"+ e.getMessage());
        logger.error(e,e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return addressComboList;
}
```

//my jsp page code

```
<tr>
                <td class="generalText"><s:text name="country" /></td>
                <td><s:select listValue="addressComboValue" listKey="addressComboId" list="#session.countryList" onchange="dojo.event.topic.publish('address_country_details');return false;"
                    name="corpAddress.country.addressComboId" />
                    <s:set name="countryId" value="%{corpAddress.country.addressComboId}" /></td>
                    <td><s:url id="corp_country" action="getStateNCityList.action" >
                    <s:param name="countryId" value="%{11}"></s:param></s:url>
                     <sx:div id="country" cssStyle="display:none;" href="%{corp_country}" listenTopics="address_country_details" formId="supplierDetails" showLoadingText=""></sx:div>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'change' JavaScript event listener to the country combo, which will use AJAX to load the list of states of the selected country, and change the options of the state combo. Do the same for the state combo, in order to load cities.

The AJAX call could invoke a struts action returning a list of HTML options, or a JSON array of states/cities. The struts action should use a Hibernate query to find the states of a country (or the cities of a state) in the database.

Comment: @ JB Nizet: I tried everything but I am not able to display the list.I am getting the size as well. I am using dojo publish and calling the action. If you have got any code or something then please let me know.It would be very kind of you.Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Ani : show us the code you have problems with, tell us what you expect and what you get instead. We're willing to help, but won't implement all your app for you.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I have updated my code.Can you please me to find solution for my problem.I am not able to poplate the list data in the jsp page.But I am able to get the list siz properly from the Database.I am using pgsql.

Comment: I don't know Struts2 and Dojo very well, but it seems to me that what you have makes the div with the "country" id load its content by calling the getStateNCityList.action when a selection change occurs in the select box. Can you confirm that you see "Enter getStateNCityList" and "Exit getStateNCityList" in your server logs when you make a selection in the country select box? If yes, then what do you send to the browser when SUCCESS is returned from the action? In other words, which JSP is being executed after this action succeeds? This JSP should generate your second select box.

Comment: SUCCESS which will return will be directed by the struts.xml file in which I would be having action tags.If the function returns success then I would be redirecting it to the same jsp. Thats how struts action and jsp will be handled right.

Comment: You can't return the same JSP. You must return what you expect to load dynamically in the div : the state/city select boxes, populated with the appropriate options.